# Invalid instruction adress in ESP32 Backtrace

Tags: esp32

I'm using an ESP32 WROOM and having some difficulties with a fatal error.

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x00000000  PS      : 0x00060c30  A0      : 0x800d386d  A1      : 0x3ffd9740  
A2      : 0x3ffd5c58  A3      : 0x00000005  A4      : 0x3ffbdbac  A5      : 0x00000000  
A6      : 0x00000001  A7      : 0x00000064  A8      : 0x800d2691  A9      : 0x3ffd9720  
A10     : 0x3ffd3954  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x3ffbdbaf  A13     : 0x00000009  
A14     : 0x00000004  A15     : 0x3ffd96f0  SAR     : 0x0000000a  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000014  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008751d  LEND    : 0x4008752d  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  


Backtrace: 0xfffffffd:0x3ffd9740 0x400d386a:0x3ffd9760 0x400d479c:0x3ffd9780
```

The second two pairs of adresses in the backtrace lead to the task and the function in which the error occurs, but from my understanding the first pair of adresses is invalid, because 0xfffffffd isn't even within the boundaries of the memory at all (see datasheet). I mean it's pretty understandable that the program crashes if there's an instruction adress that leads somewhere outside the memory, but I don't get how that adress is getting there, because the code/instruction is quite simple and it works for a while before it crashes.

[ESP_fatal_err](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/fatal-errors.html#instrfetchprohibited)
I don't even use function pointers...

In order to find the error (what ever it might be) first I would like to know in genereal, what can corrupt an instruction adress during runtime? Could there also be hardware related issues or something that have nothing to do with the code itself or must it be something about the code that is wrong and crashes after some time?

A simplified version of the code looks like this:

```
class aclass{
       bool set;
       int var;
       void action(){
           Serial.println("test");
          // other stuff;
       };
}

aclass aclass_array[100];

loop{

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       if(aclass_array[i].set){
               Serial.print("i = ");
               Serial.println(i); //When it chrashes, this is the last working line, although "i" is "valid" and other variables of the class member are still accesssable right before the crash
               aclass_array[i].action();
       }
  
   }
 //other stuff
}
```

Comment: 1) download and install [esp exception decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) plugin, you can possibly decode the error manually. 2) hardware error causes magic smoke or system malfunction, but software implementation (stack overflow, heap fragmentation/leakage, etc.) generates panic exception. 3) The class you shared and the usage currently doesn’t make a lot sense, let alone to pinpoint the root cause.